# Get values from shown cells only in MS Access table

Tags: ms-access, datatable

I have a struggle with a function in Access where I need to calculate simply the sum of a column of a table, but only those rows that are left back by the filter in a form.
Example:

[image: SUM]

The above is filtered to only show "Internal" projects.

I then need to make something that automatically calculates the sum of "Estimated time" and "Actual Time" etc. but I don't know how to access that table's filtered data. It is so easy in excel. The problem with excel is that more employees can not use it at the same time, which causes a lot of troubles.

I know i can make some bad solution by making another query of the table but then you have to select the filter in a combo box as well as the table filters. The reason why I don't just show the query is that the employees fill in new lines many times a day, directly into the table. Also they are able to delete from it, and should be.

I hope you can help me.

Best regards, Emil.

Comment: That looks like a table or query. You get a lot more control with forms. Which version of MS Access are you using?

Comment: I am using 2010. I can extend to 2013 if needed but that has not been an issue yet. How would you suggest the use of forms? This is a table, that is put on a form, where i have other functions.

Comment: @Fionnuala Also, with only the form, it is not possible to select multiple Initials, if you want to see more users task. That can not be done with combo box. Then i would need the check box, but i cant have 100 employees there.

Comment: I am sorry, but I find your English difficult to understand, so I will leave your second comment to one side. In Access 2013 (maybe 2010 as well), there is a sum function on the ribbon that works on tables and queries and changes when you filter. If you use a subform, you can add controls to the footer to sum data from the form.

Comment: Wow, okay, that is the first time i've heard my english is difficult to understand... It might be my explanation that is bad. However, I see you point in your reply. Not that I have any clue how to carry it out, but i will try.

Comment: You have since edited your second comment and it is much clearer. :)

Comment: Ah okay yes i think i did that the same time you were reading it, sorry for the first one. I misunderstood the query possibilities. I am not reading through a query, trying to manually make filters with combo boxes that has multiple choices. Then i can get the values from the actual query instead of the filtered table... (I need them in VBA)